# Rails and GrowlyFlash - How to set default options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using a gem called GrowlyFlash (https://github.com/estum/growlyflash) for notifications, it works fine however I would like to change some of the default options, according to the documentation I can do this using the following options.

```
Growlyflash.defaults = $.extend on, Growlyflash.defaults,
  align:   'right'  # horizontal aligning (left, right or center)
  delay:   4000     # auto-dismiss timeout (0 to disable auto-dismiss)
  dismiss: yes      # allow to show close button
  spacing: 10       # spacing between alerts
  target:  'body'   # selector to target element where to place alerts
  title:   no       # switch for adding a title
  type:    null     # bootstrap alert class by default
  class:   ['alert', 'growlyflash', 'fade']
```

Where is the most appropriate place to put this? I can not seem to get it to work, I am sure it is probably something simple but I get a browser error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier' so I am guessing it can not find GrowlyFlash?

Would somebody be able to give me an example, simply setting align to center.

```
Growlyflash.defaults = $.extend on, Growlyflash.defaults, align: 'center'
```

I have wrapped this in script tags and all sorts. I just can not get it to work.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you put the code?

Comment: I have tried a few places, I have tried placing it in layouts/application.html.erb as I saw something similar during my search, I have also tried placing it within javascripts/application.js -- Note that both places result in the same browser error so I am confident the code is being read, just not understood

Comment: The documentation says If you want to change default options, you can override them somewhere in your coffee/js.

Comment: Yeah that was the bit that confused me, I am not using coffeescript so I was intending to override it with plain javascript. The documentation doesn't specify the best place to do this, however the two places I have tried to override it have failed. Does the syntax look correct? I am not a javascript expert but to me it looks incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the equivalent javascript.
I cant put this in comments, that's why I am putting it here.
Check whether this helps.

```
Growlyflash.defaults = $.extend(true, Growlyflash.defaults, {
  align: 'right',
  delay: 4000,
  dismiss: true,
  spacing: 10,
  target: 'body',
  title: false,
  type: null,
  "class": ['alert', 'growlyflash', 'fade']
});
```

Comment: That is perfect - I have placed that in my application.js file however I imagine it will work in any javascript file. Thank you very much!